# How resolve unity 2019.1.0f2 error with 2D SpriteShape?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have unity 2019.1.0f2 version, and I have used 2d spriteshape(Version 2.0.0) in my project.I get the following error.

> Assets/2D SpriteShape/Extras/Scripts/SimpleDraw.cs(39,20): error CS1061: 'Spline' does not contain a definition for 'SetBevelSize' and no accessible extension method 'SetBevelSize' accepting a first argument of type 'Spline' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Can you provide more information such as was this an examply project you downloaded or an asset from the asset store?

Comment: I am using 2D Game Kit, when i updated my unity to unity 2019.1.0fa, i get this error.

Comment: I am using Mac.